# I need to set the start date and end date into a variable in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

My requirement is set the @STARTDATE variable as 01[starting day]-month[current month]-year[current year] and based upon the month @ENDDATE changes in feb 28 days, jan 31 days

```
     DECLARE @STARTDATE DATETIME
 DECLARE @ENDDATE DATETIME
```

Based on month we divide the End date

```
     DECLARE @MONTH int
     SET @MONTH=(select MONTH(getdate()))
```

HERE I AM UNABLE TO DISPLAY THE DATE IN STARTDATE.

```
SET @STARTDATE = '01-+@MONTH+-+YEAR+'
IF (
        @MONTH = 4
        OR @MONTH = 6
        )
    SET @ENDDATE = '30-+@MONTH+-+YEAR+'
IF (@MONTH / 4 = 0)
    SET @ENDDATE = '29-+@MONTH+-+YEAR+'
ELSE
    SET @ENDDATE = '28-+@MONTH+-+YEAR+'
```

Comment: After you find the @startdate, only add 1 month then substract 1 day using DATEADD() function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select @STARTDATE = dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, current_timestamp), 0) startdate,
       @ENDDATE   = dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, current_timestamp) + 1, -1) enddate
```

Comment: When we trying to retrieve data between `@STARTDATE` and `@ENDDATE`. Then the record will not be retrieved on which transaction date is same as `@ENDDATE`. Because the time of `@ENDDATE` is 12:00 AM.

Comment: @Nimesh - if you're wanting to search datetime data that has a time component, it's usually better to use an *exclusive* end point for the search (i.e. here you'd set `@ENDDATE` to the 1st of the following month) and then use `<` rather than `<=` in your comparison.

Comment: @Nimesh Damien is right. But, when you are trying to filter records then the record on last date will not be retrieved if transaction date containing time.

Comment: @danta and Nimesh question is asking for first and last day of the current month. I don't think your speculations are valid since the purpose for those dates has not been described.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2012 introduced [EMONTH() end of month function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/end-of-month-eomonth-function-in-sql-server-2012.aspx) which returns the last date of the referenced month

Here is an example

```
SELECT EOMONTH(GETDATE())
```